# Emptypage not working with \balance?

Tags: two-column

When I use `emptypage` together with `\balance`, it seems to fail to work. Emptypage should clear headings on page 4 of the example. Emptypage works fine with the example code, without `\balance`. How do I get it working correctly?

Simple example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\begin{document}
\balance
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: emptypage fails to clear headings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`balance` redefines `\cleardoublepage` so `emptypage` does nothing. Just add the functionality to what `balance` is doing, that is `\thispagestyle{empty}`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{balance}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@BAcleardblpage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\balance
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Be sure to load `emptypage` before `balance` or the latter will redefine `\cleardoublepage` according to the kernel definition and not the one modified by `emptypage`.

However, loading `emptypage` seems useless, if you do the balancing at the end of every chapter.